# Подобие слайдера на asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Здравствуйте!

Вот пример банального слайдера. Изображения хранятся в папке img, всего изображений 8, начиная от 1.jpg и заканчивая 8.jpg. При нажатии на кнопку изображения должны меняться, увеличиваясь на 1, но при нажатии на кнопку изображение с 1.jpg увеличивается только до 2.jpg и все. Почему не увеличивается дальше? Подскажите, если кто знает.

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
   <br />
   <br />
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
  </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
 int pic = 1;
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Image1.ImageUrl = "img/" + pic + ".jpg";
  Label1.Text = pic.ToString();
 }
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //увеличиваем название изображения на 1
  pic++;
  //если название больше 8
  if(pic > 8) {
   pic = 1;
  }
  Image1.ImageUrl = "img/" + pic + ".jpg";
  Label1.Text = pic.ToString();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что поле pic не запоминает свое состояние.
Для запоминания текущего номера можно использовать скрытое поле формы.
Для этого добавьте на форму HiddenField  `<asp:HiddenField ID="picNumber" runat="server" Value ="1" />`
а код класса замените на

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int pic = 1;
    if (int.TryParse(picNumber.Value, out pic))
    {
        //если название больше 8
        if (pic > 8)
            pic = 0;
        pic++;
        picNumber.Value = pic.ToString();

        Image1.ImageUrl = "img/" + pic + ".jpg";
        Label1.Text = pic.ToString();
    }
}
```